# I want to add 1 hour to my time zone (GMT) in R Language

Tags: r, offset, timezone-offset

Please I would like to add 1 hour to my time zone in R programming environment. I am using the GMT time zone.  I would like my time zone to be 1 hour ahead of GMT(i.e GMT+1) in R. So for example, if the time is 3PM GMT for example, I would like my system time within R to read 4PM.

Please how can I achieve this within the R environment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to provide some sample data.

Still, "lubridate" should work for you in case your data is in the correct Format which I can not evaluate. Assuming your data is called "df"

```
library(lubridate)
df_new <- with_tz(df, 'GMT+1')
```